# Get attribute list after a django query filter

Tags: python, django, model

I have a WathList model:

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Auction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}\t\tItem: {self.item}"
```

and I want to obtain all the *item* after performing a query

```
def view_watchlist(request):
    active_listings = Auction.objects.filter(status=True)

    # watchlist_items = Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user).values('items')

    # for watchlist_item in watchlist_items:
    #     print(watchlist_item.item)
    # print(watchlist_items.values('items'))

    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "listings": active_listings,
    })
```

to pass all the watchlisted items. Is it possible to make it without using a for loop?

I tried to use .values method, .values_list and .only but did not work out:
To make it work I created a empty list and a for loop

```
def view_watchlist(request):
    watchlist_items = Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user).only('item')
    watchlist = []
    for watchlist_item in watchlist_items:
        watchlist.append(watchlist_item.item)

    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "listings": watchlist,
    })
```

But I suspect there is a more elegant way to do it. Maybe using **related_name** when defining the model?

Comment: I suspect that you may need the `select_related` like `Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user).select_related('items')`. Then in your template do the loop. `for listing in listings: listing.item`.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do, but maybe you can do: `Auction.objects.filter(watchlist_set__user=request.user)`. Did not test it, but should work, let me know and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX this will raise an error cause `watchlist_set` is not a field. Maybe you wanted to say `Auction.objects.filter(watchlist__user=request.user)` and this is valid too.

Comment: Well @AlexDotis, I do not know how to infer that `watchlist` is a field of the `Auction` model. The OP did not write the `Auction` model definition. However, I could infer the "django default related name" when not provided for the `item` foreign key, which should be `watchlist_set`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 0):

I implemented solution suggested by [@AlexDotis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6833134/alexdotis) and it worked perfectly.

```
def view_watchlist(request):
watchlist = Auction.objects.filter(watchlist__user=user)
return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
    "listings": watchlist,
})
```

Comment: Sorry, it was @AlexDotis solution. But thank you so much all for your support!
(I am kind of new on stack overflow)